# NodeJS code working in local but not working in azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create a app service in Azure with a simple API login that works fine in local but fails in Azure.

```
const express= require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
const mysql = require("./DbConnect").connection;
const port = process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyparser.json())

app.post("/login", (req, res) => {

    let user  = req.param('user',null);
    let password = req.param('password',null);
    
    let qry = "select * from user where username ='" + user + "' AND password='" + password + "'";
    
    mysql.query(qry, (err, results) => {

        if (err)
            res.status(500).send("DB is not available!")
        else {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                res.status(200).send(results);
            }else{
                res.status(404).send("Email Or Password InCorrect")
            }
        }
    });

});
```

When I run this in local using postman, I promptly get "DB is not available!" error message. But When I run this in azure app service I get ":( Application Error". Please note that the build and deployment was successful. What am I doing wrong?

The application insights say the following

```
2022-11-21T06:18:19.890232847Z > nodemon App.js
2022-11-21T06:18:19.890236947Z 
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148319009Z node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:942
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148355110Z   throw err;
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148360910Z   ^
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148372410Z 
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148377310Z Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli'
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148381210Z Require stack:
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148384910Z - /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/nodemon
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148388810Z     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:939:15)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148392710Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:780:27)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148396510Z     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148400310Z     at Module.patchedRequire [as require] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/applicationinsights/node_modules/diagnostic-channel/dist/src/patchRequire.js:14:46)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148404310Z     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148407911Z     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/nodemon:3:13)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148412411Z     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148416111Z     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148419811Z     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148423511Z     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12) {
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148427211Z   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148430811Z   requireStack: [ '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/nodemon' ]
2022-11-21T06:18:21.148434611Z }
```

But my package.json has nodemon

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon App.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Visual Studio` or `VS Code`?

Comment: Enable Log Streaming, then you'll be able to figure out what the problem is. Also where is the listening code? app.listen(port, ..) Add a log there as well.

Comment: VS code, just added app insight details too

Comment: How you are deploying your App ?

Comment: Using azure and git. YAML has npm install, this is also working fine, deployment is also successful but the application is not running it seems!

Comment: Could you please share your Git Repository Source?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this using Docker!

Package.json should have

```
"main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
```